# How Collections.Concurrent library work under the hood?

Tags: c#, .net

Someone can explain how Collections.Concurrent library are work ?
How we get the thread-safe ?
Is their performance are good ?

Comment: They use a concept of locking/unlocking, semaphores, queues, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect the concurrent collections implementation by yourself [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs) (this is for `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`, other collections you can find using the left navigation pane) and get the exact picture of how they work.

The implementation depends on the collection type. It uses `volatile`, `SpinWait`, `Interlocked` and `lock`.

More information about performance is available in this [paper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/PerformanceCharacteristicsOfThreadSafeCollection.pdf).